# add fixed parameter to await callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, d3.js, callback

I am attempting to load some files asynchronously using d3's queue, defer and await. The problem is trying to do so in a loop, and for each item in the loop, store the fetched data in the dictionary:

```
var myDictionary = {};

// e.g. hierarchy = ["State", "County"]
hierarchy.forEach(function(geo) {
    queue()
      .defer(d3.json, 'assets/data/geo/' + geo + '/' + geo + '.json')
      .defer(d3.csv,  'assets/data/geo/' + geo + '/' + geo + '_info.csv')
      .await(myFunc);
});

function myFunc(error, jsonData, csvData) {
    // need access to geo
    console.log(geo);

    myDictionary[geo].jsonData = jsonData;
    myDictionary[geo].csvData  = csvData;
}
```

in myFunc, I would like access to geo to fill in the appropriate keys in the dictionary, however passing them inside `.await.myFunc(geo)` would print `undefined` inside myFunc.

I don't know whether this problem pertains to Javascript's callback functions, or D3's await(), or both.

Any recommendations?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
function myFunc(geo) {

    return function(error, jsonData, csvData) {
        // geo available here
        console.log(geo);

        myDictionary[geo].jsonData = jsonData;
        myDictionary[geo].csvData  = csvData;
    };
};
```

Then:

```
var myDictionary = {};

// e.g. hierarchy = ["State", "County"]
hierarchy.forEach(function(geo) {
    queue()
      .defer(d3.json, 'assets/data/geo/' + geo + '/' + geo + '.json')
      .defer(d3.csv,  'assets/data/geo/' + geo + '/' + geo + '_info.csv')
      .await(myFunc(geo));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add it as a task so it gets passed into your myFunc.

```
queue()
  .defer(d3.json, 'assets/data/geo/' + geo + '/' + geo + '.json')
  .defer(d3.csv,  'assets/data/geo/' + geo + '/' + geo + '_info.csv')
  .defer(callback=>callback(geo))
  .await(myFunc);
...
function myFunc(error, jsonData, csvData, geo) {
    console.log(geo);
}
```

Comment: this did not seem to work for me, as "undefined" gets printed.  `geo` is a string type.  Am i missing something?